# App file is not generated from XCODE 4.2

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, code-signing

The .App file is not generated when building an IOS application with XCODE 4.2, I need this file to share it with the team in order to test the application in a few of registered devices.
Additionally I can't find the build folder inside the project's root folder. 
By the way the application is running perfectly inside the simulator and I have a valid profile and a valid apple certificate to sign up the application. help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look in the following path:

> /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Products

Comment: In addition to this, XCODE 4.2 has an option in File menu, option Project Settings, so you can see the Path where the build process leaves its output. You can change it switching to whatever of the 3 options available:Default, project-relative,custom.